# How to make a simple loop more generic

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

The below method will concatenate all warnings into one string. It works but obviously need to create almost the same method again for info and error.

```
struct MyItem
{
  std::vector<std::string> errors;
  std::vector<std::string> warnings;
  std::vector<std::string> infos;
};
std::vector<MyItem> items;


std::string GetWarnings()
{
  std::string str;
  for (auto item : items)
  {
    for (auto warn : item.warnings)
    {
      str += warn;
      str += " ";
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

What would be a good generic way to implement one "Concatenate" method? One solution would be to define an enum (error\warning\item), pass it as input argument and make a switch case on argument value. Any more elegant solutions?

Comment: Could you use a delegate to retrieve the specific string vector from the object? Something like passing in a lambda like `[](const MyItem& item) { return item.which_element_you_want; }`.

Comment: You could use Eric Niebler's [Range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).

Comment: Have you tried using a single function that concatenates a `std::vector<std::string>` which gets passed in by reference, and then simply calling it, for all three vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *pointer to member* to extract a specific field from an object:

```
auto concatenate(
        const std::vector<MyItem>& items,
        const std::vector<std::string> MyItem::* member
) {
    std::string str;
    for (const auto& item : items) {
        for (const auto& element : item.*member) {
            str += element;
            str += " ";
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<MyItem> items{
        {{"err11", "err12"}, {"w11"}, {"i11", "i12", "i13"}},
        {{"err21"}, {"w21", "w22", "w23", "w24"}, {"i21"}}
    };

    std::cout << "all errors: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::errors) << '\n'
              << "all warnings: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::warnings) << '\n'
              << "all infos: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::infos) << '\n';
}
```

And, if you have members of different types in your struct (note that the above solution works only for `vector`s of `string`s), you can turn `concatenate` into a function `template`:

```
struct MyItem {
    std::vector<std::string> errors;
    std::vector<std::string> warnings;
    std::vector<std::string> infos;
    std::vector<char> stuff;            // added
};

template <typename T>                   // now a function template
auto concatenate(
        const std::vector<MyItem>& items,
        const T MyItem::* member
) {
    std::string str;
    for (const auto& item : items) {
        for (const auto& element : item.*member) {
            str += element;
            str += " ";
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<MyItem> items{
        {{"err11", "err12"}, {"w11"}, {"i11", "i12", "i13"}, {'1' ,'2'}},
        {{"err21"}, {"w21", "w22", "w23", "w24"}, {"i21"}, {'3'}}
    };

    std::cout << "all errors: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::errors) << '\n'
              << "all warnings: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::warnings) << '\n'
              << "all infos: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::infos) << '\n'
              << "all stuffs: " << concatenate(items, &MyItem::stuff) << '\n';
}
```

Note that I also changed your `auto item` occurrences in your `for()` loops to `const auto& item`s in order to avoid unncecessary copies.

Alternatively, you can use a *projection* to extract your elements. In this implementation, we use a `template` to accept any type of a function that will take your `MyItem` and return the desired element:

```
template <typename Proj>
auto concatenate(
        const std::vector<MyItem>& items,
        Proj projection
) {
    std::string str;
    for (const auto& item : items) {
        for (const auto& element : projection(item)) {
            str += element;
            str += " ";
        }
    }
    return str;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<MyItem> items{
        {{"err11", "err12"}, {"w11"}, {"i11", "i12", "i13"}, {'1' ,'2'}},
        {{"err21"}, {"w21", "w22", "w23", "w24"}, {"i21"}, {'3'}}
    };

    auto errors_projection =
            [](const MyItem& item) -> const std::vector<std::string>& {
        return item.errors;
    };

    auto warnings_projection =
            [](const MyItem& item) -> const std::vector<std::string>& {
        return item.warnings;
    };

    auto infos_projection =
            [](const MyItem& item) -> const std::vector<std::string>& {
        return item.infos;
    };

    auto stuff_projection =
            [](const MyItem& item) -> const std::vector<char>& {
        return item.stuff;
    };

    std::cout << "all errors: " << concatenate(items, errors_projection) << '\n'
              << "all warnings: " << concatenate(items, warnings_projection) << '\n'
              << "all infos: " << concatenate(items, infos_projection) << '\n'
              << "all stuffs: " << concatenate(items, stuff_projection) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: @LernerCpp I simply copied OP's implementation to change as little as possible, but I guess that it's better to make that change and explain it in an edit, thank you.

Comment: Good feedback, thank you. Thought the third option was really interesting. What do you mean by the term _projection_ in this context? Is that a C++\template term?

Comment: @Lars I believe this is more of a C++20 term, however I suspect it being in use way earlier. A *projection* is a mapping function that takes an element and returns something else. Most usually used with C++20 *rangified algorithms*.